# Does Qt use ClearType for rendering text in Windows?

Tags: windows, qt, cleartype, text-rendering

Does Qt use ClearType for rendering text (on Windows), and if so, what do I need to set to enable ClearType support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does (at least text in my app looks exactly the same as text in Explorer).
It's enabled automatically according to the system setting.

Comment: I think ClearType is disabled by default in WinXP and the option to turn it on is burried somewhere deep in the advanced options. More options are offered by <a href="http://www.microsoft.com/typography/cleartypepowertoy.mspx">ClearTypePowerToy</a>.

Answer (score 1):

there' a Control Panel Extension for that - [ClearType Tuner.cpl](http://www.mediafire.com/?8kt7sv1afpupigl)